# I need an idea of how to put stuff in session without using a form or navigate away/refreshing the page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to use seo friendly urls so im not using url parameters in the normal way.

My urls look like this http://mywebsite.com/the_dark_knight_rises

I need to put some data from my dropdown menus in session or request to pass back to the server.

My submit button is a an anchor with a link like above. Again i am not using forms for search engine discoverability.

```
<a href="http://mywebsite.com/the_dark_knight_rises">get a movie</a>
```

Since my urls have to stay pretty and i cannot use forms, i am stuck at putting stuff from my webpage in session or request.

Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onclick` event of `<a>` to execute a JS function that makes an ajax call that puts the stuff in the session.

Alternatively, put the options in a form and, with onclick function, set the target to your URL and `submit()` the form. Do not forget to return `false` so the link is not followed.

Comment: regarding your session suggestions, return false from what? can you please explain more

Comment: It applies to the second option (submit a form). If the function called by `onclick` returns `false`, the browser will not send the request for the URL in the `href` attribute. Since you are sending the request by submitting the form, you do not want to send that request. For the first option (send an ajax request to put the data in the session, and then follow the link) you want such function to return `true`